# How to serialize an object to generate a list of childs?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

There is the following `XML`:

```
<X>
    <Y att="true">FOO</Y>
    <Y att="false">BAR</Y>
    <Y att="true">TEST</Y>
</X>
```

How could I create the serializable class in `C#` to serialize and generate an `XML` like the `XML`above?

Remember that I can't create more tags, I need to generate exactly these `XML` serializing the object.

Comment: Apply the `[XmlElement("Y")]` attribute to all your classes?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy if you need only a class. I pasted your xml to [this website](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

and here is result

```
   /* 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    */
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="Y")]
    public class Y {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="att")]
        public string Att { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="X")]
    public class X {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="Y")]
        public List<Y> Y { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't knew about `XmlText` attribute.

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)

Comment: @OnlyaCuriousMind A better design would have `Y.Att` as a `bool` and would not require any further modification